# PHP - Creating a custom profile page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a website with a login & register form, I have also a `myprofile.php` webpage where I show the user his information, but, how can I let the website make an automatic webpage for every new user which is able to be shared. Such as:
`www.siteurl.com/username`
**or**
`www.siteurl.com/user.php?id=1234567`
that users can share with their friends or something like so?

I am using `PDO`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a public profile page for each user in a database, all you need to do is pass the `$_GET` parameter into the query of your database:

```
$query = 'SELECT public_info FROM users WHERE id = ?';
$result = $dbc->prepare($query);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result->bindParam(1, $id);
echo $result->queryString;
```

With the above query, `$result` will be dependent on whatever is passed in the `id` parameter of the URL. `user.php?id=1` will output information for user 1, and `user.php?id=2` will output information for user 2.

You can then use **[`.htaccess`](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)** to 'prettify' the `$_GET` parameter of the URL into whatever you'd like.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks Obsidian Age,

Comment: But,

id = ? is right or I have to replace with another thing?

Comment: No problem, and no; that's a [**prepared statement**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). By running `bindParam()` I am passing the `$id` variable **into** the `?`. This is an important part of preventing [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). `$id` is **automatically** updated from `$_GET['id']` (the URL parameter).

Comment: excuse me, this code you provided above, i should put in register.php or a new file. Also, is it only the code I will put to make their link then I start typing their information or I have to modify something?

Comment: This should definitely **not** got in `register.php`! It is code used to **output** information that is already stored in a database. It should be written on the profile page where you are trying to display the user's information, such as `user.php`. Obviously it's not the 'only' code you'll need; you'll need to add your database connection information, and modify the columns in the `SELECT`. Save the database connection as `$dbc` for the example above. The page will automatically display the information for the user specified in the `$_GET`, so you just need to give out `user.php?id=1` etc.

Comment: @MarwanK.Elzeer up vote the question since you accepted it !! lets the guy who helped you get 10 extra repu :) !

Comment: @Timino -- Thanks, and while I appreciate the upvote (and encouragement), Marwan can't actually do it himself yet; you need 15 reputation to be able to [**vote up**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) ;)

Comment: I marked it as helpful, Iam new to stackoverflow and I don't know how to really use it.

By the way obisidian:
my register code :
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

 $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

 if( $stmt->execute() ):
  $message = 'Successfully created new user';
 else:
  $message = 'Error';
 endif;

endif;

?>

Comment: When i tried the code you gave me it said :  Undefined variable: dbc in C:\wamp64\www\summer-project\profile.php on line 8

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\wamp64\www\summer-project\profile.php on line 8

How do i solve that?

Comment: I made file profile.php
and I put codes : <?php

session_start();

require 'database.php';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?';
$result = $dbc->prepare($query);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result->bindParam(1, $id);
echo $result->queryString;

?>

<h1><?= $user['email']; ?></h1>


Then go to profile.php?id=1

And I have error I told you in previous comment

Comment: The registration code is completely irrelevant; as long as your table has user information in it, with an `id` column, that's all that matters. The error comes from you not defining `$dbc`. As I **already said** in my last comment to you, you'll need to **initialise** `$dbc` to point to your PDO connection. Like `$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=DB", $user, $pass)`. You need to set those variables up **as well**. I'd also recommend checking the [**formatting help article**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and taking the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).